# Get List Title in SharePoint designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a requirement that i need to catch the List title in a sharepoint 2010 designer workflow from list.

Can any one please exlain how to catch the List title

Regards,
Suresh Pydi

Answer (score 1):

you could define a new variable and save the URL Path of the List within the newly created variable. After that just extract a substring at the position of the Listname.

For instance your URL Path to the List is:

'http://shppage/Lists/NameOfList/AllItems.aspx'

just get the substring after Lists/ up to until /AllItems

In this Case, copy Substring from 20 to 30(Into the Variable:ListName).

Regards

Ben

Answer (score 1):

The list's **Title** is not guaranteed to be part of the list's **Path**.

The OOTB string functions in SPD 2010 Workflows are weak, to say the least. And index based substring methods are only useful for non-reusable workflows.

It's ridiculous that something as simple as the list URL, path or title aren't available from the Workflow Context.

I'm sorry to say that the only way to achieve this is with a 3rd party product or custom workflow actions.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround that accomplishes what you need for an individual list.

Create a new text column with a Default value of the list's Title. This will allow you to access the list title from the "Current Item" context within the workflow.

Note that this value will be incorrect if the title name changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your WF as a Reusable WF based on your list content type, then create an association form parameter, so that you can write list name when you associate your WF to the list. Now you have this parameter available in your WF.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom list which ties an ID number to a List title. Within the workflow, reference the List/ID pair to get your title.

This would work similar to u/henry's answer, but will allow you to change the List title in 2 places instead of for every list item's hidden field.