# Get the URL from the hyperlink column for workflow

Tags: workflow, document-library, url, hyperlink

I have list with 500+ records. There is a hyperlink column called "TargetURL". As all of us know SP saves hyperlink in ["http://portal.site.com/sitecoll/doclib/Forms/someview.aspx", description ] format.

I have a workflow and I need to extract the doclib portion from the URL segment so I can get the document library name. Possible?

Substring? but how ? any tips will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me but I had to put first result in a variable and then add another build string action

```
http://[^/]+/[^/]+/
```

http://portal.cab.com/SalessiteCollection/October2012Library/Forms/customview.aspx 
Result: October2012Library/Forms/customview.aspx (you can store this in a variable)

```
(/Forms.*)
```

October2012Library/Forms/customview.aspx
Result: October2012Library

Comment: Bill: This worked. Just 2 steps. If someone can combine both regex into one that would be even great. LOL. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

Have you tried this?

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
string listname = String.Empty;
try
{
    SPList list = web.GetList(HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
    if (null != list)
    {
        listname = list.Title;
    }
}
catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException ex) 
{
    //... Handle the exception 
}
```

Comment: Daniel: Not sure how this helps me. I have 1 list with 500+ records. And there is a hyperlink column that's populated with links to various document libraries. I am simply trying to get the document library name from the hyperlink column.

Comment: With this code, changing the "HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl" by your url, you will get the Document Library name... But I agree that is not performatic. In your case, there will be a pattern like you posted http://site/sitecoll/doclib/... it will always be this way?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40712/get-list-title-in-sharepoint-designer-workflow almost looks like it. I dont see any substring after or before function in WF. they are only available xslt.

Comment: var url = "http://site/sitecoll/doclib/Forms/AllItems.aspx";

            var docLib = url.Replace("http://", string.Empty).Split('/')[2];